# Java Bulk Import

Tags: java

Will java bulk import sub packages inside one package?

For example I have this directory:

```
- PackageA
   - PackageB
      - anotherClass.java
   - PackageC
      - myClass.java
   - app.java
   - someClass.java
```

If I use this following java code will my classes "anotherClass" and "myClass" be available on my code?

```
import PackageA.*
```

or do I have to use this code?

```
import PackageA.*
import PackageA.PackageB.*
import PackageA.PackageC.*
```

Comment: You will have to import each package individually. 2nd method is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things here:

A) no, these imports are not "recursive"; you only import the classes from the specific package, not of its sub-packages

B) bulk imports are considered "bad style" by most coding style conventions and tools

(eclipse for example will automatically turn them into specific imports if you use <kbd>ctrl-shift-o</kbd> "organize imports")

Answer (score 1):

You will have to different use imports like

```
import PackageA.*
import PackageA.PackageB.*
import PackageA.PackageC.*
```

Please note that `PackageA` is different from `PackageA.PackageB`

As pointed in another answer, bulk imports are not recommended. So better would be to use

`import PackageA.PackageB.anotherClass`